# CTIA TRRS to 2 x TRS (for laptops): is the mic plug TR shorted together for bias power?

Tags: microphone

When you connect a (CTIA) mobile headset TRRS plug to a PC with separate green/pink jacks you can find Y-splitters TRRS(F) to 2 x TRS(M).

My question: since the PC mic-in(pink jack) expects 3 conductors and provides 5V bias power on R do these Y-splitters short T&R on the mic-plug for bias power to the headset mic?

My understanding: in CTIA the mic uses only two conducters RS with bias power across them (so I was wondering how PC bias power gets over to the headset).

Comment: Why would they? Then the headset microphone will see only two conductors.

Comment: I tried to find a more definitive source. [This diagram](https://wiringall.com/image/trrs-to-trs-wiring-diagram-3.png) looks useful, but its [source](https://wiringall.com/trrs-to-trs-wiring-diagram.html) leaves a lot to be desired.